# iis metabase not accessible even after running as admin

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

installed vs 2013 and when i start to create new websites and hit enter the error occurs that 
"configuring IIS express failed with the following error"
"unable to access the IIS meta base . you do not have sufficient privilege to access IIS websites on your machine."

i checked the program feature turn on or off , i reinstalled visual studio 2013 and after it i run it as an administrator but error remains.

I am using visual studio 2013 with windows 8.1 64 bit

please anyone provide the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so many hours of waste i jump to a conclusion that 
i am using windows 8.1 64 bit and vs 2013 
sql server 2014.
i removed iis and iis express from "add or remove programs"
i installed iis-10 express and restarted my system.
my system worked like hell.